# Neo4j - Find node and all relationships where one relationship matches

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am building a system where a User can authenticate with one of several Providers - e.g. Google, Twitter, Facebook, etc.

In my data store, I'm modelling this as having a :USER node for each User record, a :AUTH_PROVIDER node for each Authentication Provider, and then a Relationship from :USER to :AUTH_PROVIDER for the users authentication details at that provider. This works great.

I've also got a DAO method to load a User by the internal User ID, which returns an object containing - amongst other things - the details of all the Providers that the User is related to. This works great too. The query for that is simply

```
MATCH (u:USER{id:{id}})-[r:AUTHENTICATED_BY]->(p:AUTH_PROVIDER) 
RETURN u AS user, COLLECT({auth:r, provider:p}) AS providers
```

What I'm now trying - and struggling - to do is a DAO method to load the same User record, but resolved by the Provider link. So, for example, load the User details for the User with ID "abcde" at Provider "google".

I've got *something* working, but it's not great.

```
MATCH (p:AUTH_PROVIDER{id:"google"}), (u:USER)-[r:AUTHENTICATED_BY]->(p1:AUTH_PROVIDER) 
WHERE (u)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"abcde"}]->(p) 
RETURN u AS user, COLLECT({auth:r, provider:p1}) AS providers
```

In particular, the Neo4J browser warns me "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns"

Is there a better way to achieve the same thing? Specifically:
* Find the :USER node that is linked to a particular :AUTH_PROVIDER node by a particular Relationship
* Return that :USER node, and *all* of the :AUTH_PROVIDER nodes that it is related to

The other things that I've tried - which I've not got written down - either return only the one matching :AUTH_PROVIDER node or else all of the other :AUTH_PROVIDER nodes, but never the complete set.

Cheers

Edit: This will create some test data to show what I mean:

```
CREATE 
    (u1:USER{name:"Graham"}), 
    (u2:USER{name:"Bob"}), 
    (p1:AUTH_PROVIDER{id:"google"}), 
    (p2:AUTH_PROVIDER{id:"twitter"}),
    (p3:AUTH_PROVIDER{id:"facebook"}), 
    (u1)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"123"}]->(p1), 
    (u1)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"456"}]->(p2), 
    (u1)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"789"}]->(p3), 
    (u2)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"abc"}]->(p1), 
    (u2)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"def"}]->(p2), 
    (u2)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"ghi"}]->(p3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does not build a cartesian product and return the desired data:

```
MATCH (u:USER)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"123"}]->(:AUTH_PROVIDER {id:"google"})
MATCH (u)-[r:AUTHENTICATED_BY]->(p:AUTH_PROVIDER)
RETURN u AS user, COLLECT({auth:r, provider:p}) AS providers
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. Using my newly added test data in the original post, and adjusting that query to match, it will return the correct User, and the correct details for the non-Google provider, but not the one that actually matches the query. Specifically it returns: 

MATCH (u:USER)-[:AUTHENTICATED_BY{id:"123"}]->(:AUTH_PROVIDER {id:"google"}),
(u)-[r:AUTHENTICATED_BY]->(p:AUTH_PROVIDER)
RETURN u AS user, COLLECT({auth:r, provider:p}) AS providers

[{"auth":{"id":"456"},"provider":{"id":"twitter"}},{"auth":{"id":"789"},"provider":{"id":"facebook"}}]

Comment: Hello @Graham. I have edited the answer. Take a look! Thanks!

Comment: I have reused the first `MATCH` of `u` in the second query. This way the only cost involved in the second MATCH is the expansion to all `p`s.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)